# How can we upload an audio file by using drag and drop method in drupal CMS

Tags: drupal-7

How can we upload an audio file by using drag and drop method in drupal CMS , I have a input box `type="file"` and i need to upload an Audio file by using drag and drop function and hook in Drupal CMS.

Comment: i want this functionality in comment section can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

This module should be helpful for this.
https://www.drupal.org/project/dragndrop_upload

For Drupal 6
https://www.drupal.org/project/dragndrop_uploads

Comment: thanks  for reply i want this on drupal 6 scott i want drag n drop file upload feature on below comment . so how i am do that ...

Comment: sorry the tag said 'drupal-7'... see updated answer.